# Twig override block inside include

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am trying to override blocks that are included.

```
{# index.twig #}
{% extends "default.twig" %}
{% block content %}
  html page content
{% endblock %}
{% block footer %}
  javascript
{% endblock %}

{# default.twig #}
{% include "header.twig" %}
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
{% include "/layouts/resources/footer.twig" %}

{# footer.twig #}
{% block footer %}
{% endblock %}
```

I have also tried embed and that didn't work either.

```
{# index.twig #}
{% extends "default.twig" %}
{% block content %}
  html page content
{% endblock %}
{% block js %}
  javascript
{% endblock %}

{# default.twig #}
{% include "header.twig" %}
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
{% embed "/layouts/resources/footer.twig" %}
  {% block footer %}
    {% block js %}
    {% endblock %}
  {% endblock %}
{% endembed %}

{# footer.twig #}
{% block footer %}
{% endblock %}
```

I read this could be done with 'include with' but I couldn't get that to work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works only with a trick. You have to hand over the "block" as variable.

I removed some lines of your example so thats easier to read:

index.twig

```
{% extends "default.twig" %}
{% block content %}
  html page content
{% endblock %}
{% block footer %}
  javascript
{% endblock %}
```

default.twig

```
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
{% include "/layouts/resources/footer.twig" with {footer: block('footer')} %}
```

footer.twig

```
{% if footer is not empty %}
    {{ footer|raw }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for. I tried that but didn't change the block in footer.twig to a variable.